# XPath query to extract information from XML

Tags: xml, xpath

This may be a tricky one, although I'm no expert when it comes to XPath. Been racking my brain for days.
I'm trying to extract certain elements from an XML file to create a table, from which I then need to extract individual values via extractValue:

```
SELECT [extractValue statements] FROM TABLE( XMLSequence( extract( lv_xml, lv_xpath) ) ) t;
```

Every line in the table (one column) should contain one fragment of the XML where the required element occurs no more than once. Its parent nodes should be extracted into the table as well. The thing is that in the XML source, the required element may have siblings that match my requirements too. I need the siblings to end up in a separate line in my results table.

The XML looks similar to this (just with a lot more content, and with different ID's):

```
<element id="Address">
  <assignment name="name1" category="cat1" />
  <field id="field1">
  </field>
  <field id="field2">
  </field>
  <field id="field3">
    <assignment name="name5" category="cat2" />
    <assignment name="name12" category="cat2" />
  </field>
</element>
<element id="PersonInfo">
  <field id="field1">
  </field>
  <field id="field2">
    <assignment name="name17" category="cat1" />
  </field>
  <field id="field3">
  </field>
  <field id="field4">
  </field>
</element>
etc etc
```

I want the 'assignment' elements, plus their ancestors. But like I said above, my restults table must not contain more than one 'assignment' element per line. What I've tried so far appears to extract the lot if two of them are siblings.
In addition to that, 'assignment' can be a child of 'element' or a child of 'field', which probably adds complexity.

To make it 100% clear, my result needs to look like this (in order for the subsequent extractValue to work):

```
<element id="Address">
  <assignment name="name1" category="cat1" />
</element>

<element id="Address">
  <field id="field3">
    <assignment name="name5" category="cat2" />
  </field>
</element>

<element id="Address">
  <field id="field3">
    <assignment name="name12" category="cat2" />
  </field>
</element>

<element id="PersonInfo">
  <field id="field2">
    <assignment name="name17" category="cat1" />
  </field>
</element>
```

I've been playing around with XPath queries, but no luck so far. I was expecting

```
//assignment/ancestor-or-self::*
```

might do the trick, but I was obviously wrong. Is there a way of achieving what I want?

Comment: So does each of your entry have top most parent: `element`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Yes. <element> always exists. <field> exists sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Can you make use for XSLT?

Comment: Um. Without really knowing what I'm talking about 100%, does that depend on the dev environment - or is it just a matter of converting the XML source? I can modify the XML in any way I want, I don't need it after extracting the data. - I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 3.2, not sure if that requires any specific extension.

Comment: Well XSLT is designed for these kind of things. It makes use of XPath. It is to convert an arbitrary XML file to a new layout, such as your desired output. I'm not sure if your thing is possible with a single selection statement.

Comment: I'll be more than happy to try & see if it works. Also, if it's easier to split the select up into several steps, I'm open to suggestions. I'm just completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <element id="Address"> 
    <assignment name="name1" category="cat1"/>  
    <field id="field1"></field>  
    <field id="field2"></field>  
    <field id="field3"> 
      <assignment name="name5" category="cat2"/>  
      <assignment name="name12" category="cat2"/> 
    </field> 
  </element>  
  <element id="PersonInfo"> 
    <field id="field1"></field>  
    <field id="field2"> 
      <assignment name="name17" category="cat1"/> 
    </field>  
    <field id="field3"></field>  
    <field id="field4"></field> 
  </element> 
</root>
```

With given XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//assignment"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="assignment">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::element">
    <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="field-id" select="ancestor::field/@id"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>
  <xsl:param name="field-id"/>

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="field-id" select="$field-id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>
  <xsl:param name="field-id"/>

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="field-id" select="$field-id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>
  <xsl:param name="field-id"/>

  <xsl:if test="@id=$field-id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="field-id" select="$field-id"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="assignment" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>
  <xsl:param name="field-id"/>

  <xsl:if test="@name=$assignment-name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="field-id" select="$field-id"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will yield output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<element id="Address">
    <assignment name="name1" category="cat1"/>
</element>
<element id="Address">
    <field id="field3">
        <assignment name="name5" category="cat2"/>
    </field>
</element>
<element id="Address">
    <field id="field3">
        <assignment name="name12" category="cat2"/>
    </field>
</element>
<element id="PersonInfo">
    <field id="field2">
        <assignment name="name17" category="cat1"/>
    </field>
</element>
```

Explanation:

First we have to match against all the `assignment` elements. These assignment elements can either have a `field` or `element` as direct parent. They have as unique identifier their `id` and `name` for the `element` and `field` respectively. Then we just recursive copy and do an extra check if id and/or name match. I'm using `modes` to make sure I don't have infinite recursion.

## EDIT

Id check does not seem necessary, you can just check if it has a child assignment with name. This solution works better, because it allows for nested `field` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//assignment"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="assignment">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::element">
    <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="@name"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>

  <xsl:if test="child::assignment[@name=$assignment-name]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="assignment" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="assignment-name"/>

  <xsl:if test="@name=$assignment-name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:with-param name="assignment-name" select="$assignment-name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much. I've been playing with it and adjusted it to fit my actual scenario and it works brilliantly - except for one case. 
The value of attribute "name" for the "assignment" elements does not have to be unique. An "element" or "field" element can have several "assignment" elements as children with the exact same name ("category" can also be identical, but this is very unlikely). In these cases the XSL transformation's output will contain multiple "assignment" tags per section, which means I can't process it.
Is there a way to deal with this?